# What does it mean for a region to be simultaneously a region of type 1 and type 2?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

I am going through a proof of Green's Theorem for a simple region and I understand the mathematics taking place but do not understand the origins.

'Regions that are simultaneously of type I and II are “nice” regions' is a statement I don't fully understand.

I have proved mathematically that:
$$-\iint_G \Bigg(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\Bigg) \cdot dA = \int_{\partial G}Q \cdot dy$$
and 
$$-\iint_G \Bigg(\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\Bigg) \cdot dA = \int_{\partial G}P \cdot dx$$
But I do not understand the two types of region being discussed and how a region can be simultaneously both.

Any help understanding this concept would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should include the definitions of type I and type II.

Answer (score 2):

A Type I region is essentially one that can be glued together with adjacent vertical strips. A Type II region can be glued together with horizontal strips. A square region would be both Type I and Type II, for example.

As an example that is Type I but not Type II, consider the region bounded by $x=0$, $x=100\pi$, $y=-1$, and $y=\sin x$. It can be decomposed into vertical strips, but horizontal slices would be disconnected.

The [Wikipedia article on Green's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem#Proof_when_D_is_a_simple_region) goes into more detail.

Comment: Thank you Theophile, the example of the square is a basic but helpful example.

Comment: @J.Bry You're welcome. In general, any convex shape will be both Type I and II, although (as the Wiki example shows) convexity is not a requirement.